# How to make a linked list holding objects

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I want to have a linked list containing an object

Here we have the class.
It is simple and only has a String and one int. Called `s` and `n` respectively.

```
public class test {
    String string = new String ();
    int n;

    public metodo (String string, int n ){
        sets(string);
        setn(n);    
    }

    public void sets(String string){
        this.string = string;
    }

    public void setn(int n){
        this.n = n;
    }

    public String gets(){
        return string;
    }

    public int getn(){
        return n;
    }
}
```

In each node there will be an instance of the class test.
I want to be able to call each node and then call the object in the node calling the class test.

Here is my linked list

```
import java.io.*;

public class Node
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader ( System.in));

    test m;
    int n;
    static Node next = null;
    String string = new String ();

    Nodo head = null;

    public Nodo (test m, Nodo next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void hoho() throws IOException{
        while ( true )
        {  // This loop is for making several nodes with diferent information
            System.out.println("String");
            string n = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(" Int ");
            n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            m = new test(string, n);
            Nodo nod = new Nodo (m, null);
            Nodo.siguiente = head;
            head = nod;
            if ( n == 0 ){ // Manual close of the loop by inserting 0
                break;
            }
        }
    }                           
}
```

Now I don't really know when to start the object `m`, if in the start or in the while.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Otherwise, why not use this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Well, the objective of the program is to be able to have dinamic buttons. Literraly xD, the button would be in the "test" class, tecnically I want to have a program that can create infinite buttons but all with different information. :P